# Проверка наличия файла

Tags: файлы, php

Есть файлы по дате

```
0105.txt 
0205.txt 
0305.txt
```

Если подходящего файла нет - должен читаться файл index.txt.

```
    <?php 
   $h=date("dm");
$filename = 'data/$h.txt';
$d=date("d.m.Y");

if (file_exists($filename)) {
  if(1==1) {
    $f=file("data/$h.txt");
    for($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++) {
        list($date)=split("::",$f[$i]);
        $k=1+$i;
        $kok= print"$date<br>";
    }
  };
} else {
        $filename = fopen( 'data/index.txt', "r" ) or die ( "Не удалось открыть index.txt" );

    }
    ?>
```

Что не так?

Вопрос закрыт: [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), [[@Fike](/users/16095/fike)](/users/16095/fike) - спасибо.

Comment: OMG вот вы изменили... $filename - имя файла, $file_handle handle

      $filename = "data/$h.txt";


зачем, ну зачем (1==1) что вы хотите этим проверить ?

и теперь вопрос, "что-то не так?" что значит ? какая-то ошибка или что ?

Comment: Нет, вчера просто не успел закрыть вопрос... Все работает, выводит так как нужно!  
eicto - спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Первые  две строки кода перепутаны местами, кавычки одинарные.

зачем `$filename = fopen( 'data/index.txt', "r" )` - не  понятно

Comment: Так, если подходящего файла нет - должен читаться файл index.txt...

Comment: так он просто открывается у вас а не читается :) и переменную лучше назвать не $filename а $fileHandler.

Comment: @Serg107, для проверки файла на существование лучше использовать функцию `file_exists()`. Понятия не имею, как оно сделано "изнутри", но простор для более оптимального использования ресурсов операционкой огроиный.

Comment: @Fike у него есть file_exists() я тоже не сразу заметил.

Comment: чтобы index.txt вывести на экран, можно readfile() использовать...

а зачем у вас там `if (1==1) {}` ??

Comment: $filename = fread( 'data/index.txt' )

Comment: зачем $filename ? $filename  это же имя файла а не его содержимое  в конце концов. мало того fread(**$handle**)